# Reading from stdin using read(..) and figuring out the size of the buffer

Tags: c, memory-management, stdin

I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there is a way to dynamically allocate a buffer when reading an input from stdin using `read(...)`
For example:

`n = read(0, buffer, sizeof ?);` How do I ensure that the number of bytes read from `stdin` (here 0) is the same as in `buffer` ?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use the system call instead of the buffered input from libc?

Comment: @sidyll: In principle there are many reasons - for example if you want another program to inherit the file descriptor and pick up reading exactly where you left off, or (this matters more for writing) if you want to know exactly how much was successfully written if and when an error occurs.

Comment: @sidyll yeah I was having some info sent to the server from a client and basically doing some checking on it. Actually what R.. said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You do a `read` into a fixed-size buffer, e.g.:

```
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
int num_read = read(0, buf, BUF_SIZE);
```

and then figure out if there's any more data available (usually by checking whether `num_read` is equal to `BUF_SIZE`, but in some cases, maybe you need to interpret the data itself).  If there is, then you do another read.  And so on.

It's up to you to deal with concatenating all the read data.

Comment: So as @Cedric Julien said, looping would be the best way to go. Thanks for your help every one!

Comment: why in the manpage, it uses the word "shall attempt". Is there any case that read will not read exactly the number of bytes specified by the 3rd argument? linux.die.net/man/3/read

Answer (score 1):

You can't (unless you've got precognitive skills) figure out the size of what you will get.

But the read method allow you to read part by part the content of stdin, if you put your read() call into a (`while your_stop_condition`) loop, you will be able to read all the stuff you need from stdin, by packets.

```
char buffer_to_read[SIZE];
int bytes=0;

while your_stop_condition
{
   bytes = read(0, buffer_to_read, SIZE);
   // do what you want with your data read
   // if bytes < SIZE, you read an EOF
}
```

Comment: I just wanted some outside perspective. Didn't want to be like since I don't know it, so it can't be done. I would love some precognitive skills though. Thanks!