# Reading from stdin

Tags: c, unix, stdin

What are the possible ways for reading user input using `read()` system call in Unix. How can we read from stdin byte by byte using `read()`?

Comment: your should read in `read()` manual

Comment: Read will do this just fine, but depending on exactly what you want to do, you may find that you have to do more than just call read - can you post your code, and explain exactly which part you have problems with?

Comment: I agree with Mats, what *excatly* are you looking for here?  Where is the problem? [There are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610064/read-stdin-in-c) also a lot of different [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503399/reading-from-stdin-using-read-and-figuring-out-the-size-of-the-buffer) of how to do [this on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237329/read-from-stdin-doesnt-ignore-newline), do you do any searching before asking the question?

Answer (score 56):

You can do something like this to read 10 bytes:

```
char buffer[10];
read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 10);
```

remember [read()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) doesn't add `'\0'` to terminate to make it string (just gives raw buffer).

To read 1 byte at a time:

```
char ch;
while(read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1) > 0)
{
 //do stuff
}
```

and don't forget to `#include <unistd.h>`, `STDIN_FILENO` defined as macro in this file.

There are three standard POSIX file descriptors, corresponding to the three standard streams, which presumably every process should expect to have:

```
Integer value   Name
       0        Standard input (stdin)
       1        Standard output (stdout)
       2        Standard error (stderr)
```

So instead `STDIN_FILENO` you can use 0.

**Edit:**
In Linux System you can find this using following command:

```
$ sudo grep 'STDIN_FILENO' /usr/include/* -R | grep 'define'
/usr/include/unistd.h:#define   STDIN_FILENO    0   /* Standard input.  */
```

Notice the comment `/* Standard input.  */`

Comment: why in the manpage, it uses the word "shall attempt". Is there any case that read will not read exactly the number of bytes specified by the 3rd argument? https://linux.die.net/man/3/read

Comment: @weefwefwqg3 read() will read fewer bytes than requested if it is interrupted by a signal, or if there are fewer bytes available than requested, etc.

Answer (score 17):

From the [man read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

```
#include <unistd.h>
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

Input parameters:

- `int fd` file descriptor is an integer and not a file pointer. The file descriptor for `stdin` is `0`
- `void *buf` pointer to buffer to store characters read by the `read` function
- `size_t count` maximum number of characters to read

So you can read character by character with the following code:

```
char buf[1];

while(read(0, buf, sizeof(buf))>0) {
   // read() here read from stdin charachter by character
   // the buf[0] contains the character got by read()
   ....
}
```

Comment: You could use `int fileno(FILE *stream)` first

Comment: @Grijesh - You can take it one step further, `stdin` is going to be 0, so you can just `read(0,...` Don't need to search around for `stdin`'s file number on *NIX systems

Comment: @Mike Yes I `stdin = 0`, `stdout = 1`, `stderr = 2` and good is its same for all OS.

Comment: @MOHAMED wait don't delete your answer., after some time I would add some details.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I m not going to do it I updated it based on your remarks

Comment: @MOHAMED Go ahead MOHAMED to improve your answer: add two points (1) you can just read using `char c`; `read(0, &c, 1)`  , (2) read() function doesn't terminate input buffer with `\0` with `fgets()` do. So in case if someone wants to use buffer as string he has to explicitly add null like: `no_byte = read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1); buffer[no_bytes] = '\0';`  This is the point where new guys do mistakes. like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847472/udp-client-receiving-a-text-file/15847675#15847675) read second error...go ahead this is what I wanted to add.

Comment: why in the manpage, it uses the word "shall attempt". Is there any case that read will not read exactly the number of bytes specified by the 3rd argument? https://linux.die.net/man/3/read