# How to assign input (from echo command) in char array in C program

Tags: c

How to assign input of echo in char array in C program?
For example:

```
$ echo "Hello, world!" | ./hello
```

I need to save string "Hello, world" to an array.

Comment: [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).

Comment: read from stdin. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883568/reading-from-stdin).

Comment: @Catweazle: that question is about using the `read()` system call, which is certainly doable, but not necessary.  There are ways to do it using the standard I/O library (`<stdio.h>`) that are probably more appropriate at this stage.

Comment: Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. We need to see your attempt at solving this along with why that didn't work. Without that it looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `echo` is [piped](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html) to the input of `hello`. To get a string as an input in C, use `fgets`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/. Here is some example code:

hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char inputarr[256];
  fgets(inputarr, 256, stdin);

  //Credit to Tim Čas for the following code to remove the trailing newline
  inputarr[strcspn(inputarr, "\n")] = 0;

  printf("Value of inputarr: \"%s\"\n", inputarr);
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/4599165) is Tim's post about his code

Shell command:

```
$ gcc hello.c
$ echo "Hello, world!" | ./a.out
Value of inputarr: "Hello, world!"
$
```