# How to pipe a c program that takes in arguments?

Tags: c

For example, say I have a program like this:

file1.c is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
         printf("one file only\n");
         return (1);
     } else {
         for (size_t i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++) {
             if(argv[1][i] != 'a') {
                 putchar(argv[1][i]);
             }
         }
         putchar('\n');
     }
 }
```

Above is a simple problem that iterates the input of argv[1] and removes every 'a'.

For example

```
$ gcc -Wall file1.c
$ ./a.out abcd
bcd
```

Is it possible to tweak this code to make piping work? As in,

```
$ echo abcd | ./a.out
bcd
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883568/reading-from-stdin)

Comment: You'll have to do that in the shell, like xargs does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to tweak this code to make piping work? As in,

Of course.

Instead of reading the contents of `argv`, you will need to read the data from `stdin` and process it as you see fit.

```
int main() {
   int c;
   while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
   {
      if(c != 'a') {
         putchar(c);
      }
   }
}
```

---

If you want to have both options available to you, you can use:

```
int main() {
   int c;
   if ( argc == 2 )
   {
      for (size_t i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++) {
         if(argv[1][i] != 'a') {
            putchar(argv[1][i]);
         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
      int c;
      while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
      {
         if(c != 'a') {
            putchar(c);
         }
      }
   }

}
```

---

If you want the code unchanged, you will have to use another helper program that converts the output of `echo abcd` to become the arguments to `a.out`. On Linux, `xargs` is such a program.

```
echo abcd | xargs a.out
```

Comment: this version could be put into the `if (argc != 2)` block of the original code to support both modes of execution, although would probably be better in that case to check `if (argc < 2)` and maybe confirm stdin is not a terminal with `isatty`.