# Why am I getting a segmentation fault when iterating over an array?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference, coredump

I extracted the function in question from my main project and simplified it in order to demonstrate the problem I have:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read_input(unsigned char **buff, unsigned int *length){

    unsigned int buff_size = 36;
    *buff = (unsigned char *) malloc(buff_size);
    memset(*buff, 0, buff_size);
    unsigned char chr;
    while((chr=getchar()) != '\n' && chr != EOF){
        *buff[*length] = chr;
        printf("%c\n", *buff[*length]);
        ++(*length);

    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    unsigned char *buff;
    unsigned int length = 0;

    read_input(&buff, &length);
    printf("%s, %i\n", buff, length);

}
```

If I run the program, and type `test`, the output is:

`t`

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried debugging the program?

Comment: *buff[*length] -> (*buff)[*length]

Comment: Note there are standard C functions for reading input see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883568/reading-from-stdin

Comment: EOF usually is -1, so your comparison won't work with `unsigned char`. Consider changing `chr` type to `int` and casting it to `unsigned char` when necessary.